# Is there any way to display exact address from google map place api?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, google-places-api

I got vicinity(address) from google map api in flutter but this vicinity contains extra keywords including number,operator etc(like QCPM+777, XYZ). All, i want to display only exact address (XYZ) without any numbers or operators. How can i do that?

I try to replace extra keywords with empty string "" using replaceAll method but it can't work properly.

Comment: Can you provide us with your sample request?

Comment: "place_id": "ChIJuymqB3HHVTcRmpOET5do_Yk",
      "rating": 5,
      "reference": "ChIJuymqB3HHVTcRmpOET5do_Yk",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
        "mosque",
        "place_of_worship",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "user_ratings_total": 1,
      "vicinity": "Q9GX+2Q2"